# Unable to deserialize ArrayOfString back to List<string> in C#

Tags: linq, c#-4.0, linq-to-xml, deserialization

I have seen this question asked, but have not found answers that work so I am asking it again.
I have a restful web service with a POST method that returns a serialized List.

```
<ArrayOfstring xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays">
<string>QoL5vA8OKgydWIn%2fdWiu70nobBrJo4N9iXeHmtM7Aj4%3d</string>
<string>vxHyJiSSSvDSZWXOdcfl5FMQC97xxGEWDO8Zy8Qp3X5CwADUbEE8ifACQHR1n7uamEaIUbf85ZuBDB8FFCNY2tJAMJ2jNw09SqGVTpMU5uI06DLtuYnJqsPIF735NOhlvRhBLPnpp62DFMCVsDNHy55UBF3Ggi06ZWTiJ8LTYIf3FYiFLPpXLZ1wWeE5chAWQGfz7zDYJa1OgSZ</string>
<string>OqGAT7Yqe6DfyVD29BeIXFyGtabVCloaC9FA1Fp20JkJ9T17ZzyqhnGxwWda7FqqyJUM8YK9OdcOCgTYrl4JxalECdtJm75TdSG8IAPQlFHp6Gidg4EwZaO9FKahlYMm5JrFpxTmLrdLgMAkYEV7gIR6zIyIByAGwYYDDwH3QCHrym3CuueRnFWAHCJu1LJbx0zRtt7g3yEaTiJ</string>
</ArrayOfstring>
```

The code performing the call is as follows below.

```
        XDocument xDocResponse = RestPOSTToXDocument(szBaseUri, szInput);

        string szNamespace = xDocResponse.Root.Name.Namespace.ToString();
        IXmlUtils utility = new XmlUtils();
        List<string> lst = utility.DeserializeList<string>(xDocResponse, szNamespace);
```

I have also attempted a different version of the call as shown below.

```
        List<List<string>> lst = utility.DeserializeList<List<string>>(xDocResponse, szNamespace);
```

Both versions of the calls generate the error provided below.

*An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Xml.dll but was not handled in user code
Additional information: There is an error in XML document (0, 0).*

My Deserialize method is provided below.

```
    public List<T> DeserializeList<T>(XDocument doc, string szNamespace)
    {
        List<T> result = null;
        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<T>), szNamespace);

        using (System.Xml.XmlReader reader = doc.CreateReader())
        {
            result = (List<T>)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
        }

        return result;
    }
```

The XML within the XDocument is valid, so I do not understand why this error is being generated. Also, even if I attempt to get the elements via navigation in the XDocument, it does not work.  If I look at the doc.Root.value, it appears that all of the strings are concatenated together into a single string.

Does anyone have any information on how I may deserialize this XDocument into a List?

Comment: There seems to be something wrong with the namespaces in your sample XML.  I wrote up a little script to serialize a list of strings, and I get the following: `<ArrayOfString xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">`, which is different than the XML you are working with.  Trying to deserialize my version with your code then works without error.

Comment: The web service uses a MediaTypeFormatter and in this case formats it as XmlMediaTypeFormatter. Why would the namespace be invalid though?

Comment: According to [**this article**](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/json-and-xml-serialization#xml_media_type_formatter), the `XmlMediaTypeFormatter` class uses a `DataContractSerializer` by default.  You need to deserialize with a `DataContractSerializer` as well.  See [**here**](http://web.archive.org/web/20130430190551/http://www.danrigsby.com/blog/index.php/2008/03/07/xmlserializer-vs-datacontractserializer-serialization-in-wcf/) for some notes about the differences - they don't generate cross-compatible XML.

Comment: Are you saying that instead of using the XmlSerializer, the XmlMediaTypeFormatter should be used instead? In other words, for simple types only something different needs to be done to deserialize. For all of my other deserialization, I create a class with public properties and the Deserialize method works fine.

Comment: Sorry, I updated my comment - I didn't know what `XmlMediaTypeFormatter` was because I had never heard of it, but I think I understand the root problem now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the assistance of mellamokb, I found the problem.  When my List is serialized, it is serialized into an ArrayOfstring.  If I take the XML and replace ArrayOfstring with ArrayOfString, the deserialization works.

This does not make much sense.  I would welcome an explanation of why this is necessary though it may have something to do with String vs string.

Essentially, I had to do the following:

```
        string szXml = xDocResponse.ToString();
        int nEndRoot = szXml.IndexOf(">");
        szXml = szXml.Replace("ArrayOfstring", "ArrayOfString");

        xDocResponse = utility.LoadXDocument(szXml);

        string szNamespace = xDocResponse.Root.Name.Namespace.ToString();
        List<string> lst = utility.DeserializeList<string>(xDocResponse, szNamespace);
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply get the response stream and deserealize into string array and store it to List

Code Snippet:

```
    List<string> listNew=new List<string>();
     using (Stream answer = webResponse.GetResponseStream())
     {                                              
       DataContractSerializer xmlSer = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(string[]));
       var stringArr= (string[])xmlSer.ReadObject(answer); 
       foreach (string item in GenreList)
        {
          listNew.Add(item);
        }
     }
```